# URL regex beginning and ending with

Tags: regex, url

How would i make a regex to only get the word "TITLE" and filter out the rest.

the title can change

Example:

> http://blogx.blogspot.com/2012/04/TITLE.html?showComment=13348745236XXXXXXX

What i got:

```
http://[a-z{1,20}].blogspot.com/{4}/{2}/______\.(.*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
blogspot\.com\/.*?([^\/]+)\.html
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30n5i)

`([^\/]+)` is a negated character class that will match anything than a slash till there is ".html".

You will find the "Title" in capturing group 1.

Your try has other issues, apart from the missing title part

```
http://[a-z{1,20}].blogspot.com/{4}/{2}/______\.(.*)$
           ^^^^^^^              ^^^ ^^^
```

1. The quantifier has to be outside of the character class.
2. You provided here only the quantifier. This would match 7 `/` in a row (btw. depending on your regex flavor and/or the regex delimiter you need to escape the slash).

Using your regex the solution could look like

```
http://[a-z]{1,20}.blogspot.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/([^\/]+)\.(.*)$
```

See it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?30n5o)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=http://blogx\.blogspot\.com\/\d{4}/\d{2}/).*?(?=\.)
```